# Showing iOS app files within in the Files app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get images that my iOS app writes to its own Documents folder, to appear in the 'Files' app as a folder under 'On my iPhone', and allow them just to be opened as standard images by whatever apps are installed on the phone, like these apps do:

[image]

I've set `UIFileSharingEnabled` in the Info.plist which means they appear in the 'Music' app on macOS when connecting the phone. However, I haven't been able to get them to appear within the Files app itself.

I see references to `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` - but this seems to require building a UI within the app. I've seen other apps do what I want without any custom UI - I just want to expose the files, not do anything 'fancy'.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As well as `UIFileSharingEnabled` add this to your `Info.plist`

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

Here is my test code. Works well for me on macOS 12, using Xcode 13.2,
targets: ios-15 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on real ios-15 devices.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

    struct ContentView: View {
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "globe")!
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image).resizable().frame(width: 111, height: 111)
        Button(action: {
            saveImage(file: "globe")
        }) {
            Text("save test file")
        }
    }
    
    func saveImage(file: String) {
        do {
            let fileURL = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent(file)
                .appendingPathExtension("png")
            try image.pngData()?.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("could not create file: \(file)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT1: Starting from a "new" project in Xcode.

I created a new ios project from scratch, using Xcode 13.2 on macos 12.2-beta.
Copied and pasted the code in my answer. Then in the `Targets->Info`

I added the following entries:

`Application supports iTunes file sharing` YES

and

`Supports opening documents in place` YES

Compiled and ran the project on a iPhone ios-15. In the `Files` app,
went to `On My iPhone` and the `TestApp` folder was there, and inside was the "globe"
image file.

Added the mac catalyst in `General -> Deployment Info`,
removed the `App sandbox` from the `Signing & Capabilities`.

Compiled and ran the project on a iMac macos 12.2, and in the `Documents`
directory was the `globe.png` file.

Comment: thanks @dudette, but this doesn't work for me - I've had this flag set, can see the files when the device is connected to iTunes/Music (so I know the files are written to the correct location) and yet nothing appears in the Files app on the mobile device itself?

Comment: I've just tried your example too in a brand new app in Xcode 13, with the same problem? Any suggestions on how to diagnose where this is going wrong? thanks

Comment: see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @dudette - I must have tested some of these combinations only on the simulator (where it doesn't seem to work) instead of my device. This works for me now, many thanks.

Comment: @dudettesupportUkraine do you maybe know how I can make my cloud storage app appear outside `on my iPhone`, in Locations list in Files app?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with cloud storage app.

Comment: I had to restart my iPhone for the files to show up. Hope this helps someone.